# How to replace words that come a specific word and has its first letter in upper case with R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to find a way to replace the 3 following words that arrive after a specific one and have their first letter in upper case. I need this to delete first name in a corpus.

For instance, here is what I have:

```
name <- c("Hello Mr Whatever His Name. How are you ?")
```

And what I need:

```
Hello Mr . How are you ?"
```

I couldn't find anything similar on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is it based on two letter word?

Comment: 2 or 3 max because many times i have name and last name

Answer (score 3):

You could use `gsub` for that:

```
name <- c("Hello Mr Whatever His Name. How are you ?")
gsub("(.*Hello Mr )[^\\.]*(\\..*)", "\\1\\2", name)
```

returns:

```
[1] "Hello Mr . How are you ?"
```

Explanation:

The expression selects three parts:

1. Everything up to and including Hello Mr
2. Everything after that up to the first dot .
3. Everything including and after the dot .

Then it replaces the whole string with only the first and third part

## Edit 1: (Answering the *actual* question):

```
gsub("(.*Hello Mr )(?:[A-Za-z]+ ){2}[A-Za-z]+(.*)", "\\1\\2", name)
```

returns:

```
[1] "Hello Mr . How are you ?"
```

Explanation:

1. Everything up to and including Hello Mr
2. 3 consecutive words
3. Everything after that

Disclaimer: You should run some tests to make sure that it works for all possible cases...

## Edit 2: Limits of the suggested regex:

```
name <- c("Hello Mr One two Three. How are you ?",
          "Hello Mr One Two Three. How are you ?",
          "Hello Mr one two three How are you ?",
          "Hello Mr ONE Two. Three. How are you ?",
          "Hello Mr _ . ) How are you ?")

gsub("(.*Hello Mr )(?:[A-Za-z]+ ){2}[A-Za-z]+(.*)", "\\1\\2", name)
```

returns:

```
[1] "Hello Mr . How are you ?"              
[2] "Hello Mr . How are you ?"              
[3] "Hello Mr  How are you ?"               
[4] "Hello Mr ONE Two. Three. How are you ?"
[5] "Hello Mr _ . ) How are you ?"
```

Comment: Thanks a million times! but if there is no punctuation this wouldnt work ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you already mentioned: **replace the 3 following words that arrive after a specific one**... give me a sec

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is almost that. Do you know what i should add if i don't want to include "Hello Mr" ? I will try to adapt your code, but this synthax is not easy at all!!

Comment: I know, regex is extremly powerful and useful but I'm always struggling with it. But there are some helpful toos like regex101.com, a website where you can test and "develop" your regex. https://regex101.com/r/8yHw0t/1 this link should lead you to where I tested your regex

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
gsub(gsub(".*Hello Mr (([A-Z][a-z]+\\s){2}[A-Z][a-z]+).*","\\1",name),"",name)
```

where the inner `gsub` is to extract the pattern to be removed, and the outer `gsub` is to remove the matched pattern.

Or a method similar to the approach by [@dario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120243/12158757)

```
gsub("(.*Hello Mr )(?:([A-Z][a-z]+\\s){2}[A-Z][a-z]+)(.*)","\\1\\3",name)
```

such that

```
# [1] "Hello Mr . How are you ?"
```